# How to run TFLite model on the RaspberryPi

Tags: python, tensorflow

I trained the model SSD_InceptionV2_coco on my PC with GPU on a customer image set. it works great on my pc so move it to my pi which run ok but super slow 0.7 FPS :( so i read about TFLite and used the script that comes on the Object_detection folder called "export_tflite_ssd_graph.py" 
it created a new .pb file but i run it on the script that works with regular frozen file i get the following:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "light_A.I_CT.py", line 81, in 
>       od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/protobuf/message.py",
>   line 185, in ParseFromString
>       self.MergeFromString(serialized)   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py",
>   line 1083, in MergeFromString
>       if self._InternalParse(serialized, 0, length) != length:   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py",
>   line 1120, in InternalParse
>       pos = field_decoder(buffer, new_pos, end, self, field_dict)   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/decoder.py",
>   line 610, in DecodeRepeatedField
>       raise _DecodeError('Truncated message.') google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Truncated message.

The code i am using is the following:

> ## Load the Tensorflow model into memory. detection_graph = tf.Graph() with detection_graph.as_default():
>
> ```
> od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
> with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
>     serialized_graph = fid.read()
>     od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
>     tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
>
> sess = tf.Session(graph=detection_graph)
> ```

Its pretty basic and taken from the examples but i dont know if i need to do something else as all the TFLite samples are for IOS or Android.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot a TFLite model with regular Tensorflow code, and you need to build TFLite instead. You may want to see [this](https://medium.com/@haraldfernengel/compiling-tensorflow-lite-for-a-raspberry-pi-786b1b98e646) as an example.

Comment: Thanks for the info, i did get further as now i have a bit better understanding of TFLITE but i still have problems with the current sample:

ImportError: /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/interpreter_wrapper/_tensorflow_wrap_interpreter_wrapper.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6tflite12tensor_utils24NeonVectorScalarMultiplyEPKaifPf